# Regex to remove what ever comes in front of "\" using powershell

Tags: regex, powershell

wanted one help, wanted a regex to eliminate a "\" and what ever come before it,

```
Input should be "vmvalidate\administrator" 
and the output should be just "administrator"
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
$result = $subject -creplace '^[^\\]*\\', ''
```

removes any non-backslash characters at the start of the string, followed by a backslash:

**Explanation:**

```
^      # Start of string
[^\\]* # Match zero or more non-backslash characters
\\     # Match a backslash
```

This means that if there is more than one backslash in the string, only the first one (and the text leading up to it) will be removed. If you want to remove everything until the *last*  backslash, use

```
$result = $subject -creplace '(?s)^.*\\', ''
```

Comment: [Same site but basic syntax link.](http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html)

Answer (score 11):

No need to use regex, try the split method:

```
$string.Split('\')[-1]
```

Comment: `$string.Split('\')[1]` is a bit more cheerful.

Comment: In case the input doesn't contain any `\ ` (e.g. input is already *administrator*), `[1]` will return nothing whether `[-1]` will return the input.

Answer (score 3):

```
"vmvalidate\administrator" -replace "^.*?\\"
```

- ^ - from the begin of string
- .* - any amount of any chars
- ? - lazy mode of quantifier
- \ - "backslash" using escape character ""

All together it means "Replace all characters from the begin of string until backslash"

Answer (score 0):

This is the way I used to do things before I learned about regex or splitting.

```
"vmvalidate\administrator".SubString("vmvalidate\administrator".IndexOf('\')+1)
```