# Looking to compare group memberships against a network share

Tags: powershell, permissions, active-directory, directory

I am new to this site and fairly new to PowerShell.  So far I am loving both!

I am currently trying to put together a PowerShell script that will look at all ACL's within all sub folders of a certain share or folder, then compare those ACL's against a users group membership.  So let's say Tom says "I want Jerry to have the same access as I do, but ONLY for the CONSTRUCTION share and all of it's sub folders, no other areas outside of the CONSTRUCTION folder.  I would like to then see all the groups that Tom is a member of that reside within the CONSTRUCTION folder's subs so then I can add Jerry to only those groups.

So far I have a few pieces that I think I need, but am not quite sure how to piece them together to give me what I need:

`Get-Acl -Path "\\\share\construction" | Format-List` will give me a list of the ACLs, but only for this folder

`get-childitem -Path \\\share\construction -dir -Recurse | format-list -Property name` will give me a list of all sub folders within CONSTRUCTION

`Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership Tom` will give me a list of all the groups Tom is a member of

Now for the hard part, which is to string it all together so I can say "Ok, THESE are the groups that I need to add Jerry to in order to have his access be the same as Tom's within the CONSTRUCTION folder and its subs only (as some sub folders may have different acl's than the parent and I want him added to those as well).

As I say, I am new to PowerShell so please let me know if I am way off base with these cmndlets.  Any help that can be offered would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just putting Jerry in the same groups as Tom might give him more access than you want (if one group gives Tom access to another folder in another share), and it won't necessarily give him the same access that Tom has (if Jerry is in a different group which has DENY override to something, then adding him to Tom's allow group won't make a difference). Does your group and folder share ACL design cover both these possibilities?

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  For the most part, the word "con" or "construction" would be in the ACL name itself but not always, but I would still love to see the group names.  And in my corporation, we do not deny access, you're either granted access or you are not.  Denials are not used. I've been after such a script for a little while now.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the community! Great start getting into PowerShell its quite fun!

You have the right idea for sure starting with those three lines. I don't want to just provide you a whole script to run what you want. But rather keep encouraging you along the right lines.

To achieve what you want here, you will need:

*Group Membership of Tom*

*Locations Groups*

*Compare Toms Groups to the location*

*Add Jerry to this missing groups*

Lucky for us PowerShell can do all of this.

**Step 1: Retrieve Group Membership**

```
$TomsMembership = Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership Tom | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name
```

**Step 2: Retrieve Access Groups of the Folder**

```
$LocationACL = (Get-Acl -Path \\share\construction).Access | Select-Object -ExpandProperty IdentityReference
```

**Step 3: Compare User Groups to Location Groups**

```
$AccessGroups = Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $LocationACL -DifferenceObject $TomsMembership -IncludeEqual -ExcludeDifference
```

**Step 4: Output Groups User Gains Access to Folder with**

```
Write-Host $AccessGroups.InputObject
```

Now that you have the above main components it should be quite easy to throw together a script to do what you need!

Please let me know if you have any issues with the above.

**Helpful Tips**
`Get-Help` is your best friend, using `Get-Help` with the cmdlets will give you a great insight into what the cmdlets can actually do.

Comment: Thanks a ton Lachie.  Only one issue.  The NAME property looks like "ACL-TEST (CHANGE)  and the IdentityReference property looks like "Contoso\ACL-TEST (CHANGE)" with the domain prefix so the comparison sees them as 2 different InputObjects.  Is there a way to make them the same format?  I've been scouring help but cannot see an answer.  Any thoughts?

Comment: I'm going to try adding this:

function append-text { 
  process{
   foreach-object {"Contoso\" + $_ }
    } 
  }

Comment: I think I am posting my code wrong in here,  The posts show up weirdly formatted.  Sorry about that. :/

Comment: Hi Kenny, yeah you can use something like how you have written here or you could use regex to remove anything before the `\`e.g:

`$LocationACL = $LocationACL -creplace '^[^\\]*\\', '' `

This would chance the identity reference to match the same as the NAME property you were mentioning before without needing a function.

Credit to:

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16694662/regex-to-remove-what-ever-comes-in-front-of-using-powershell

Comment: Done!  Thank you very much Lachie.  I finally went with the below code (I hope it displays properly as I still dont know why/how this site butchers my posts.   $A = (get-childitem c:\test -dir -Recurse | get-acl).Access | Select-Object -ExpandProperty IdentityReference
$B = Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership chucktest | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name
$A = $A -creplace '(?s)^.*\\', ''
$A = $A | select -uniq

Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $A -DifferenceObject $B -IncludeEqual

Comment: Nice one! @KennyC If you can mark this as the answer so people don't keep looking to answer it that would be great :)